# Definition of (multi)tensor categories in Etingof's tensor category.

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, monoidal-categories

Let $k$ be an algebraic closed field. Etingof defined the term *multitensor category* and *tensor category* as follow:

Supposed $\mathcal{C}$ is a locally finite $k$-linear abelian rigid monodial category, if the bifunctor $-\otimes-:\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ is $k$-bilinear on morphisms, then we call $\mathcal{C}$ is a *multitensor category*. Moreover, if $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{1})\cong k$, then $\mathcal{C}$ is a *tensor category*.

In this definition, we require such a monodial category to be rigid, but we do not require the left duality functor: $X\mapsto X^*,\ f\mapsto f^*$ to be $k$-linear. I think we really want this condition to hold. Why it is not included in the definition? Can we deduce it?

Comment: It’s true automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I know how to prove it. If tensor is $k$-bilinear, then we can prove $X^*\oplus Y^*$ is the left dual of $X\oplus Y$. to prove this, we can suitablely define $\operatorname{ev}_{X\oplus Y}$ and $\operatorname{coev}_{X\oplus Y}$, and then prove $(X^*\oplus Y^*, \operatorname{ev}_{X\oplus Y}, \operatorname{coev}_{X\oplus Y})$ is the left dual of $X\oplus Y$ by the definition of dual.